# How to increase memory used desktop application in visual studio C# to avoid MemoryOutOfBound exception

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, video, emgucv

I am using Emgu library to create video from a set of images,
most of the time when i running the program it generates MemoryOutOfBound Exception, Code part of using videoWriter() is shown below

```
p = dp.FileName + ".avi";
VideoWriter v = new VideoWriter(p, 24, hd.Width, hd.Height, true);
string filename = "";
int iiii = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
{
    filename="frames" + j + ".bmp";
    hdd = new Bitmap(jj + "\\new1\\" + filename);
    hd = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(hdd);
    v.WriteFrame(hd);
}
v.Dispose();
```

Comment: you could start with also Disposing the Bitmap instance in `hdd` and I'm not sure which type Image exactly is but if that one implements IDisposable as well, do the same. Report your progress.

Comment: `Dispose` is not instant, maybe it's enough to instruct GC about memory allocations (`AddMemoryPressure`/`RemoveMemoryPressure`). Otherwise you have to call `GC.Collect` and wait.

Comment: Don't know if this will help: http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/2-4GB_game_memory_limits_and_solutions#LAA_in_General and https://helloacm.com/large-address-aware/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require your program to be able to use a large amount of memory (>2GB), you will need to compile for x64 platforms (and be running on one).
If you need large objects (>2GB), you will also need to add the following code to your App.config file:

```
<runtime>    
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

Note: I believe you need to be running .NET 4.5 or higher for this feature